# Modifying reference type parameters in Swift; are changes immediately visible outside?

Tags: swift, multithreading, parameters, pass-by-reference, swift-playground

I have a Swift playground that contains several classes in the source folder. These classes have `tick()` functions that are called as fast as possible with a `while true { }`. I am using a parallel thread to do this, to stop Xcode from locking up, with this code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    BackgroundThread.startMainLoop(scene: scene)
}

// other file
public struct BackgroundThread {
    public static func startMainLoop (scene: SKScene) {
        let songController = SongController()
        let uiManager = UIManager(scene: scene)

// The UIManager is going to modify this scene.
// Will the changes be available to BackgroundThread and/or the main file?

        while true {
            songController.tick()
            uiManager.tick()
        }
    }
}
```

Because the main playground script is very slow, I have moved the repeating loop to a compiled class in the Sources folder.

I am passing an `SKScene` object to a `UIManager` compiled class, which I will need to update the UI in this (relatively complicated) scene faster than the main playground script can manage.

The main playground script calls a `startMainLoop()` function in the parallel thread. It passes in the `SKScene` object. This function never returns, since it contains a never-ending loop. Is there a way I can modify the passed object in a manner that modifies the scene displayed on the screen, live, without the function ever having to return (which means that `inout` is not an option), assuming this does not happen by default?

Comment: I may be proven wrong, but I thought there is *no* "by reference" in Swift. The default is by value, and "inout" only "copies" the value to a function and "copies back" the result - as in there is *two* memory spots taken up. Also, I can speak for SpriteKit, but with UIKit you really *need* to do all UI updates in the main thread. (If either of these are factually incorrect, I'll remove this comment.)

Comment: @dfd No, there are definitely reference types in Swift... isn't that the main difference between `class` and `struct`? Does Swift do something strange like copying a class to pass it to a function rather than passing a pointer?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and post relevant code demonstrating your issue/question.

Comment: @rmaddy I have added an example. There is not a lot to see; most of the information is in the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference type means the value is a reference -- i.e. a pointer to an object. When you pass or assign a reference, you get a copy of the reference (it is pass-by-value without `inout`), but multiple copies of the reference point to the same object, and modifications to the object through any reference that points to it is visible through any other reference that points to it.

Comment: Indeed, it turned out that it worked as I planned without any modification.